# Calling Twain driver from 64 bit application

Tags: c#, .net, twain

I need to call TWAIN API from .NET (C#) application compiled for x64 target platform. Are there any advices on 3rd party vendors providing 64 bit twain implementations?

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately not. As far as i know doesn't exist a TWAIN driver native 64bit. 
I think that the only solution is compiling your app at x86 32bit.

Another option(commercial) is the [TWAIN 64-32 Bridge](http://www.eztwain.com/twain-bridge.htm) .